# Power automate - PUT is not allowed method

Tags: power-automate, power-automate-custom-connector

I'm working with power automate consuming apis with POST and GET methods.. but when I started working with PUT method... power automate blocked my request in some way. Here's the error:

[image]

The output:

[image]

I've added headers such as User-Agent : Mozilla/5.0 but it doesn't work, also I've reviewed the backend side and PUT is one of the allowed method.

I didn't see any key of these on ngnix, only the basic stuffs.

Note: I'm using a gateway in java in order to consume these API's where as I wrote lines before, GET and POST works perfect but PUT doesn't. Also consuming the API using swagger without the gateway, PUT works perfect.

Is there any thing that I'm missing here?

Comment: Have you tried making the same request with a tool like Postman?

Comment: Yeah, also the same result as power automate shows, and HTML with 405  Not Allowed as a title.